# Installing HgEclipse for IBM RAD 7.0

Tags: mercurial, ibm-rad, hgeclipse

I would like to hear if anybody has had luck with installing [HgEclipse](http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE) on [IBM RAD (Rational Application Developer for WebSphere) 7.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/application/)? I'm asking this on behalf of my coworkers, who want to use Mercurial, but who cannot make HgEclipse work. Does anybody use this combination, perhaps with an older version of HgEclipse?

RAD 7.0 is built on top of Eclipse 3.2 -- I know this is neither the newest version of RAD nor the newest version of Eclipse but that's the versions they have to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt Eclipse 3.2 is supported.
Actually, [ticket 10420](http://www.javaforge.com/issue/10420) reports Eclipse 3.4 is not supported!...

Even the latest [IBM RAD 7.5.5.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/application/) is based only on Eclipse3.4 and would propably not support HgEclipse.

Comment: I'm surprised that they don't keep better compatibility between different versions... thanks for the answer, though!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Rational Application Developer 8.0 Beta.

You find more information on this page.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/rad/Rational+Application+Developer+Version+8.0+Open+Beta

FYI: The help does not list Mercurial as compatible software.

The postings on this site are my own and do not necessarily represent the positions, strategies, or opinions of IBM